# How such an endless sequence of power chords is called?

Tags: chord-progressions

C4 C5

D4 D5

E4 E5

F4 F5

G4 G5

A4 A5

B4 B5

It sounds like an endless stairs of power chord going upwards. I know there is a Wikipedia page for that but I do not know how to ask Google or Wikipedia, it just doesn't get found.

Comment: I'm not aware of any special name for it. What information about that sequence are you trying to find out?

Comment: @Aaron - feels like the OP's trying to describe a discrete Shepard scale - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shepard_tone [I'll leave it to someone smarter than me to provide the full answer, if so] ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Good thought. Elmrine, consider looking through the posts here that mention [Shepard tones](https://music.stackexchange.com/search?q=shepard+tone).

Comment: @Tetsujin - a bit like those Esher pictures, in sound?

Comment: @Tim Not quite. Shepard tones are period signals that can be interpreted as two contrary motions, one rising (or falling) in pitch and one falling (or rising) in tone. Shepards tones work by having a spectrum of multiple octaves each going in the same direction until wrapping around at some point coming and going niente towards or from this wrapping point. They will thus not sound like an ever rising scale of equal notes, but they will at the same time change tone towards the octave below or above. It is just that the brain cannot pinpoint a specific break of octave.

Comment: @Tim You can see it as an Esher picture with a general downward slope, so everything works out.

Comment: This isn't really endless, is it?  It will end when you run out of room on the guitar or escape the human hearing range.  You're just going up the C major scale.

Comment: You gave me the answer I am looking for, it is the Shepard tone. I need this effect for creating some kind of suspense in my composition. @Edward it is really endless, look at spectral analysis of this on Wikipedia. I can not vote to any of you because your answers are in "comment" form not in "answer" one - but thank you all.

Comment: So, I think the question is whether it is possible to create a Shephard tone on the instrument that OP wants to use. Perhaps a skilled string ensamble could do it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is a concept called harmonic planing- wikipedia defines this as a series of chords with the same intervallic structure without regard for a tonal center.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_harmony#:~:text=In%20music%2C%20parallel%20harmony%2C%20also%20known%20as%20harmonic,of%20two%20or%20more%20melodies%20%28see%20voice%20leading%29](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_harmony#:%7E:text=In%20music%2C%20parallel%20harmony%2C%20also%20known%20as%20harmonic,of%20two%20or%20more%20melodies%20%28see%20voice%20leading%29).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a Shepard Tone also sometimes called the “Musical Barber Pole” or “The Sonic Barber Pole”?

> The Shepard Tone is an audio illusion that creates the feeling of consistent, never-ending rising/falling.

https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/shepard-tone-illusion/